# Setting frame.origin.x view.frame.width does not completely hide view off screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2, frame

I want to set LoginView out of the screen to the right side so it wont be visible.
I have used this code and tested it on iPhone 4S

```
LoginView.view.frame.origin.x = LoginView.view.frame.width
```

But the result is not what I expected.

**The result**

[image]

I have tried to print `LoginView.view.frame.width` to the console and it gave me 320.0, but if I want to completely move the view out of the window I have to set `LoginView.view.frame.width` to 328.0

What are those 8 extra points ?

Comment: It's possible your image view's contents are overlapping its bounds. Does it have Clip Subviews enabled?

Comment: When it's onscreen, does it fill the screen? It looks like you've got 8 points of margin...

Comment: @Tim yes it fills the screen but I have found out that its even larger by 4 points from on both sides, what can be causing it ?

Comment: Are you setting it to a particular width? Are you allowing it to size to its contents? Is its content larger than its frame and you have Clip Subviews disabled?

Comment: @TwoStraws I have set constraints (trailing margin space) to -20 so it covers 100% of width in story board, but it seems to be causing the problem, because if I set it to -16 it covers 100% of iPhone simulator width and it works as expected, but in storyboard it gave me unwanted white space. So which one is correct -20 or -16 ?

Comment: @Stevik You want your picture to go edge-to-edge, so use the Pin menu then deselect "Constrain to margins". NB: I am now worried because you're mixing Auto Layout and frame adjustments, but that's a separate problem!

Comment: @TwoStraws deselecting Constrain to margins helped. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Stevik Great! Would it be OK if I summarised my comments as an answer so that others can see it too?

Comment: @TwoStraws I have already done that, but if you have prepared more detailed answer, do it

Answer (score 0):

Comment from @TwoStraws solved my problem.

When creating constrains you have to deselect Constrain to margins, so to have it full screen it should be like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons this could happen:

1) It's possible your image view's contents are overlapping its bounds. Does it have Clip Subviews enabled?

2) You're forcing the image view to be a particular width.

3) You've made the image view size itself to its contents.

4) Your constraints are trying to match the view's margins, not the view itself.

In this particular case – with some trial and error! – we figured out that **the correct solution was 4**. Hopefully this answer will prove useful to others coming to this question in the future.